# Static Images and CSS files are not loading Through IIS

Tags: css, asp.net, windows, amazon-web-services, iis

I have developed asp.net code in which I am passing some static image and css files.
When i am trying my local PC through Visual Studio it's loading as expected but When I am hosting through IIS in AWS EC2, My static images and CSS files is not loading.
I think it seems to be Static Content issue in IIS so I enabled IIS feature for static content, still the issue is same.
Please Help me in this.

Comment: open the browser debug tools and check where the images are asked from - probably is the url that you have set.

Comment: @Aristos I have checked the URL and its pointing the correct Image. but still no luck.

Comment: If your static images and CSS files is not loading, then you can use the F12 developer tool to view the error message in the console. then solve the problem according to the error message.

Comment: @ManishParida need to give more information's beside the luck - how anyone can help you with out give the error code, what is not find, what the extensions - maybe to hire a programmer ?

Comment: The issue is with Folder permission to special account is not given from which IIS pool is running

Comment: You can access permission by right-clicking on a folder, choosing Properties and then clicking on the Security tab. To add permissions for a special account, click the Edit button and then add special account.